# Keras in R and tensorflow backend

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I need to limit the number of threads running my neural network using these instructions here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4740.

However, I am using keras in R, and I am not sure how do I access the tensorflow implementation used in keras I load in R using

`library("keras")`

I can call `library(tensorflow)`, however, isn't it loading a library copy unrelated to the one loaded by keras? And I cannot find any functionality in R that allows to load tensorflow backend associated with keras in Rstudio. Also I cannot find any links to anyone doing the same.

Can someone suggest a way to do the operations in the link from R, given keras loaded with `library("keras")` (in the link tensorflow backend for keras is used to set the number of threads per core). It would also be good to know how to check which version is loaded into R by keras.

Comment: Just copy what you want to do from python to R and replace the `.` to `$`

Comment: I would like to follow this question.

Comment: Ok, I can say there seems to be a function in kerasR that is called k_set_session() which seems to set the session created with tensorflow. Also conversion of types is an issue, but easy to fix. Though i need to run on the server to see if the solution works. But it is possible to at least code-up the thing in the link in R.